# Microsoft Graph API : Criteria for "relevanceScore" of scoredEmailAddresses object

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

what is the internal logic to calculate the "relevanceScore" field of people resource in Microsoft graph api ? any documentation around it publicly available ??

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put more care into grammar as it is very hard to understand you.

Comment: Can you provide more info on what you are looking for?  At a high level it's:  based on multiple communication and collaboration patterns (such as in email and Skype) and business relationships (i.e. your org directory).

Comment: Are there any customization allowed ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/resources/scoredemailaddress.md),

> The relevance score of the email address. A relevance score is used as a sort key, in relation to the other returned results. A higher relevance score value corresponds to a more relevant result. Relevance is determined by the user’s communication and collaboration patterns and business relationships.

Comment: Thanks for response Lifu Huang, I was looking for info how each of these component like communication , collaboration pattern and business relationships contribute to this score. And also any customization that can be done on this.